# error C2664: 'SQLGetData' : cannot convert parameter 6 from 'SDWORD *' to 'SQLLEN *'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, 64-bit

I have the code that compiled on Visual Studio 2008 in 32 bit mode. Now I am trying to compile the same in 64 bit mode. 
Point where I am having this error is:

```
SDWORD temp=0;
SDWORD & readlen = (pValue?*pValue:temp); 
retValue=::SQLGetData(hStatement,mCurrentCol=column,cType,actualbuff,len,&readlen);
```

I tried to google the error message but did not find solution that I can use. Can anyone help me with this.
Is there any way I can typecast SDWORD to SQLLEN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual type for the sixth parameter is SQLGetData is SQLLEN*. MS' documentation also uses SQLINTEGER*. Your code is treating it as SDWORD*. It's a simple cast *IF* SQLLEN and SDWORD have the same underlying datatype. But if, say, SQLLEN is a 64-bit wide value, and SDWORD is 32-bits wide, then a cast won't suffice. In that case, you could try:

```
SQLLEN length=0;
retValue=::SQLGetData(hStatement,mCurrentCol=column,cType,actualbuff,len,&length);
if (pValue)
    *pValue = length;
```

Comment: How to assign the value to length if pValue is not null?? In old code it was
`SDWORD & readlen = (pValue?*pValue:temp); ` Because pValue coming as SDWORD in the old code, 
 I tried to type case from SDWORD to SQLLEN, but SDWORD is 32 bit and SQLLEN is 64 bit.

Comment: Try *pValue = (SDWORD)length;

Comment: That type casts length value to pValue, here length is SQLLEN and pValue SDWORD. I need to use SQLLEN, is there a way to typecast from pValue SDWORD to lenght type SDWORD. 
SDWORD is of 32 bit and SQLLEN is of 64, throws me an error!!:(

Comment: `warning C4312: 'type cast' : conversion from 'SDWORD' to 'SQLLEN *' of greater size` 
I am sorry this was the warning message not the error message. But I am still worried if its going to hurt!!

Comment: `SQLLEN temp=0;`
   `SQLLEN readlen = (pValue?*pValue:temp);`
    `retValue=::SQLGetData(hStatement,mCurrentCol=column,cType,actualbuff,len,&readlen);`
And I am not seeing any warning or errors, but I am not sure about any runtime errors at this point, because pValue is of type SDWORD.